# Finding probability function of sum of two distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

Let $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ and $Y\sim\text{Geometric}(\theta)$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent. Let $Z=X+Y$. What is the probability function of $Z$?

$P(X=0)=1-\theta$ and $P(X=1)=\theta$.

$P(Y=k)=(1-\theta)^k\theta$ for $k=0,1,\dots$

$P(Z=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)=(1-\theta)\theta$ and $$P(Z=k)=P(X=0,Y=k)+P(X=1,Y=k-1)=(1-\theta)(1-\theta)^k\theta+\theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta$$ for $k=1,2,\dots$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\{Z = 0 \} = \{X=0\}\cap\{Y=0\}
$$
and for positive integers $k$,
$$
\{Z=k\} = \left(\{X=0\}\cap\{Y=k\}\right) \cup\left(\{X=1\}\cap\{Y=k-1\}\right).
$$
It follows then that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z=0) &= \mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Y=0)\\
&= (1-\theta)(1-\theta)^0\theta\\
&= \theta(1-\theta),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z=k) &= \mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Y=k) + \mathbb P(X=1)\mathbb P(Y=k-1)\\
&= (1-\theta)(1-\theta)^k\theta + \theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta\\
&= \theta  ((\theta -1) \theta +1) (1-\theta )^{k-1}.
\end{align}